# Send JSON Object to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-app-engine

In my HTML code, I have JavaScript. In order to check whether my code worked/became a JSON object, I first sent my JSON object in a blank HTMl to print out JSON.

```
{"nodes": [{"ID": "Latin 2"}, {"ID": "Latin 2"}, {"ID": "Computer Science 2"}, {"ID": "Calculus 2"}], "links": [{"ID": 1, "target": "Latin 1", "source": "Latin 2"}, {"ID": 2, "target": "Latin 1", "source": "Latin 2"}, {"ID": 3, "target": "Computer Science 1", "source": "Computer Science 2"}, {"ID": 4, "target": "Calculus 1", "source": "Calculus 2"}]}
```

You can see that it did render as a JSON object, but when I wanted to put the JSON object in my Javascript, which is inside my HTML, I get this error code:

```
{&#34;nodes&#34;: [{&#34;ID&#34;: &#34;Physics 5&#34;}, {&#34;ID&#34;: &#34;Latin 2&#34;}, {&#34;ID&#34;: &#34;Latin 2&#34;}, {&#34;ID&#34;: &#34;Computer Science 2&#34;}, {&#34;ID&#34;: &#34;Calculus 2&#34;},
```

I am using GAE jinja to send over the JSON object.

```
#graph is all the information--> turning now into JSON
json_graph = json.dumps(graph)
template_vars = {'json_data': json_graph }
template = jinja2_environment.get_template('template/index.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_vars))
```

This is my HTML where JavaScript is embedded

```
<script>
    //json_data is from the python
    var graph  = {{json_data}}
</script>
```

Comment: You're actually just asking how to make jinja2 stop HTML-escaping.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out!